# how can I connect laravel with xampp mysql

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, laravel-9

I was trying to connect my laravek project to database but I couldnot connect with my xampp mysql. I can connect with my local downloaded mysql. but not with the xampp mysql.

I wanted to connect my project with xampp mysql and was expecting I will be able to work in phpmyadmin.

Comment: open the xampp configurattion toll aned see if the mysql server is running

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this article](https://gist.github.com/bradtraversy/7485f928e3e8f08ee6bccbe0a681a821) can help you.
Remember to edit the .env file in your project root directory to set the environment variables value

```
 DB_CONNECTION=mysql
 DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
 DB_PORT=3306
 DB_DATABASE=database_name
 DB_USERNAME=root
 DB_PASSWORD=
```

By default, the Xampp user is root , with no password